# Using a Winform as a View in C++

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, mfc, winforms-interop

im trying to use a Winform as a view in my MFC application, but i cant seem to get it to work. It compiles and runs but when starting the view it crashes indicating the control cant be created:
afxwinforms.inl

```
return CreateControl(info,dwStyle,&pt,&size,pParentWnd,nID);
```

Can someone please help me out here it would be really appreciated
I currently have the following code:

MyWinFormsView .h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <afxwinforms.h>
#include "MyViewUserControl.h"

#include "MyDoc.h"

// CMyWinFormsView view

class CMyWinFormsView : public CWinFormsView
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyWinFormsView)

protected:
    CMyWinFormsView();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
    virtual ~CMyWinFormsView();

public:
    CMyDoc* GetDocument();
    DspAnalog::MyViewUserControl^ GetControl();

public:
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC);      // overridden to draw this view
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
#endif

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    virtual BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
public:
    virtual void OnInitialUpdate();
protected:
    virtual void PostNcDestroy();

public:

BEGIN_DELEGATE_MAP( CMyWinFormsView )
END_DELEGATE_MAP()

    //afx_msg void OnTextChanged(System::Object ^ o, System::EventArgs ^ e);
    //afx_msg void OnSaveChangesClick(System::Object ^ o, System::EventArgs ^ e);
};

#ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in View.cpp
inline CMyDoc* CMyWinFormsView::GetDocument()
   { return (CMyDoc*)m_pDocument; }
#endif
```

MyWinFormsView.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyWinFormsView.h"
#include "MyViewUserControl.h"


// CMyWinFormsView

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyWinFormsView, CWinFormsView)

CMyWinFormsView::CMyWinFormsView() : CWinFormsView(DspAnalog::MyViewUserControl::typeid)
{
}

CMyWinFormsView::~CMyWinFormsView()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyWinFormsView, CWinFormsView)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// CMyWinFormsView drawing

void CMyWinFormsView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
}

// CMyWinFormsView diagnostics

#ifdef _DEBUG
void CMyWinFormsView::AssertValid() const
{
    CWinFormsView::AssertValid();
}

#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
void CMyWinFormsView::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
{
    CWinFormsView::Dump(dc);
}
#endif

CMyDoc* CMyWinFormsView::GetDocument() // non-debug version is inline
{
    ASSERT(m_pDocument->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc)));
    return (CMyDoc*)m_pDocument;
}

#endif //_DEBUG

DspAnalog::MyViewUserControl^ CMyWinFormsView::GetControl()
{
    System::Windows::Forms::Control^ control = CWinFormsView::GetControl();
    return safe_cast<DspAnalog::MyViewUserControl^>(control);
}


BOOL CMyWinFormsView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    return CWinFormsView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}

void CMyWinFormsView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CWinFormsView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // *** Workaround bottom dock initial sizing issue
   /*   System::Windows::Forms::ScrollableControl ^scrlCtrl = dynamic_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ScrollableControl^>(GetControl());
    if (scrlCtrl != nullptr)
    {   
        CRect rcView;
        GetClientRect(&rcView);
        System::Drawing::Size size(0,0);
        scrlCtrl->AutoScrollMinSize = size;
    }*/
    // *** End workaround

    CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    DspAnalog::MyViewUserControl^ viewControl = GetControl();
}

void CMyWinFormsView::PostNcDestroy()
{
    CWinFormsView::PostNcDestroy();
}
```

MyViewUserControl.h:

```
#pragma once
    #using <mfcmifc80.dll>

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    //using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace MyDsp {


    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyViewUserControl
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyViewUserControl : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl,
                                         public Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::IView,
                                         public Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::ICommandTarget
    {
    public:
    MyViewUserControl(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyViewUserControl()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: DevExpress::XtraEditors::SimpleButton^  simpleButton1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->simpleButton1 = (gcnew DevExpress::XtraEditors::SimpleButton());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // simpleButton1
            // 
            this->simpleButton1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(44, 101);
            this->simpleButton1->Name = L"simpleButton1";
            this->simpleButton1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->simpleButton1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->simpleButton1->Text = L"simpleButton1";
            // 
            // MyViewUserControl
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->Controls->Add(this->simpleButton1);
            this->Name = L"MyViewUserControl";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion

    public:
        // Implementing IView and ICommandTarget interfaces
        virtual void OnInitialUpdate();
        virtual void OnUpdate();
        virtual void OnActivateView(bool bActivate);
        virtual void Initialize(Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::ICommandSource^ cmdSrc);
        System::Void Command1Handler(System::UInt32 cmdUI);
        int iActivateCount;
    };
}
```

MyViewUserControl.cpp

```
#include "MyViewUserControl.h"

namespace MyDsp 
{

#define ID_CVIEWCMDS_COMMAND1   32771

void MyViewUserControl::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    this->iActivateCount = 0;
}

void MyViewUserControl::OnUpdate()
{
}

void MyViewUserControl::OnActivateView(bool activate)
{
    this->iActivateCount++;
}

void MyViewUserControl::Initialize(Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::ICommandSource^ cmdSrc)
{
    //Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CommandHandler^ command;

    //command = gcnew Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CommandHandler( this, &MyViewUserControl::Command1Handler );

    // Use the same control ID as in the resource.h of the MFC project
    //cmdSrc->AddCommandHandler( ID_CVIEWCMDS_COMMAND1, command );
}

// Handler for the MFC menu command

void MyViewUserControl::Command1Handler(System::UInt32 cmdUI)
{
    //this->toolStripStatusLabel1->Text = "Selected Command1";
}
}
```

Comment: When any of your applications crashes, you first instinct should be to run the program in a debugger. It will help you locate the place where the program crashes, lets you see how and from where the function was called, and let you examine variables and arguments to help you understand _what_ might have caused the crash.

Comment: Like i said however i forgot to mention the line number (122) afxwinforms.inl
return CreateControl(info,dwStyle,&pt,&size,pParentWnd,nID);

Comment: Yes, but it's a system file. If you go up the call stack to your code, where is that?

Comment: wfrmview.cpp line 108 fSucceeded=fSucceeded && m_control.CreateManagedControl(m_pManagedViewType,WS_VISIBLE, rect, this,nID);

Answer (score 0):

do you know [the microsoft mfc-winform integration example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239718%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

some hints for the start:
don't use the using on the System... namespaces, cause c++/cli some times mismatch

look at the compiler options of each c++ file in the example, there are a lot of things you have to set (/clr and so on)

Comment: Actually i used that as a starting point. Ok so now i decided to use the code which is in the example in my project and try to get that working first. now i run in to the following:  using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
causes: error C2872: 'FILETIME' : ambiguous symbol so now im stuck with multiple definitions of FILETIME :S

Comment: removing using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; solved that problem but still i have my original problem the solution now builds and runs but when the view is being created it crashes on
wfrmview.cpp line 108 fSucceeded=fSucceeded && m_control.CreateManagedControl(m_pManagedViewType,WS_VISIBLE, rect, this,nID);

Comment: why do you need winform as a mfc view, can't you use a native mfc view with winform controls?